# C : Error creating a function to Start a List

Tags: c, list, dynamic, vector

i was having no trouble making my project until the point i had to make this function :

```
#define TAMANHO 50
#define MIN 60
#define MAX 255
typedef void* PVOID;
typedef void** PPVOID;

struct ListaProdutos{
    PPVOID cabeca;
    int tamanho;
    int posicao;
};
typedef struct listaProdutos LISTAPRODUTOS;
typedef LISTAPRODUTOS* PLISTAPRODUTOS;

struct Produtos{
    int ID_Produto;
    char descricao[MIN];
    float Preco;
};


void InitLista(PLISTAPRODUTOS 1) {
1->cabeca = (PPVOID)malloc(sizeof(PVOID)* TAMANHO);
1->tamanho = TAMANHO;
1->posicao = 0;
}
```

The errors i get are the following :

error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'

error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'constant'

error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'

error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Given the fact that the void function give me those erros, i cant continue coding the vector list i was planning to do.

Any help is welcome, thank you.

Comment: What's `PLISTAPRODUTOS 1` supposed to do?  In any case, that's an illegal statement because 1 is not a valid name for a variable (and `1` is the constant the compiler is referring to).

Comment: "1" is not a valid variable name

Comment: Additionally, `typedef struct listaProdutos LISTAPRODUTOS;` should be `typedef struct ListaProdutos LISTAPRODUTOS;`

Comment: Why the down votes?  At least give a reason.  (Question meets criteria ***[here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)***)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 is an integer, not a structure, so you can't dereference anything from it. You'll need a new variable name to get the errors to go away.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to fix one spelling error, and later, use a non-numeric for a variable name, then it builds:

***Change this:***

```
typedef struct listaProdutos LISTAPRODUTOS;//spelling error, to match struct in your OP, should be >>>L<<<istaProdutos 
typedef LISTAPRODUTOS* PLISTAPRODUTOS;

struct Produtos{
    int ID_Produto;
    char descricao[MIN];
    float Preco;
};  

void InitLista(PLISTAPRODUTOS 1) {
1->cabeca = (PPVOID)malloc(sizeof(PVOID)* TAMANHO);
1->tamanho = TAMANHO;
1->posicao = 0;
}
```

***To This:***

```
typedef struct ListaProdutos LISTAPRODUTOS; //corrected spelling of ListaProdutos 
typedef LISTAPRODUTOS* PLISTAPRODUTOS;      //(had listaProdutos before)

struct Produtos{
    int ID_Produto;
    char descricao[MIN];
    float Preco;
};


void InitLista(PLISTAPRODUTOS legalVariableName) //replaced "1" with variable name
{                                                     //
                                                      //
    legalVariableName->cabeca = (PPVOID)malloc(sizeof(PVOID)* TAMANHO);
    legalVariableName->tamanho = TAMANHO;
    legalVariableName->posicao = 0;
}
```